# LINQ on Directory.GetFiles with filtering and sorting with multiple sort criteria

Tags: c#, linq, windows-runtime

The following works fine for getting a list of *.png and *.jpg files from a specified directory, sorted by a file name.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/"));

List<string> fileNames = di.GetFiles("*.*")
 .Where(f => f.Name.EndsWith(".png") || f.Name.EndsWith(".jpg"))
 .OrderBy(f => f.Name).Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

I wanted to enhance the above by making sorting work first with a **file extension** and then by a **file name**, hence:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/"));

List<string> fileNames = di.GetFiles("*.*")
  .Where(f => f.Name.EndsWith(".png") || f.Name.EndsWith(".jpg"))
  .OrderBy(f => new {f.Extension, f.Name}).Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

This flags a runtime error: `At least one object must implement IComparable` and suspect the OrderBy `new {f.Extension, f.Name}` may be incorrect??

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to specify multiple orderings you can use the `ThenBy` method after the initial `OrderBy` call:

```
List<string> fileNames = di.GetFiles("*.*")
  .Where(f => f.Name.EndsWith(".png") || f.Name.EndsWith(".jpg"))
  .OrderBy(f => f.Extension)
  .ThenBy(f => f.Name)
  .Select(f => f.Name)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code to solve your problem

```
List<string> fileNames = di.GetFiles("*.*")
      .Where(f => f.Name.EndsWith(".png") || f.Name.EndsWith(".jpg"))
      .OrderBy(f => f.Extension)
      .ThenByDescending(f => f.Name)
      .Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```